# Split String with varied amount of input data

Tags: swift, string, string-interpolation, swift-optionals

I have a string that looks like this:

```
https://product/000000/product-name-type-color
```

I used a split to separate this strings, but Im having problems because the link can come without the description or the id

```
guard let separateLink = deeplink?.split(separator: "/") else { return }

let linkWithoutProductDetails = "\(separateLink[0] ?? "")//\(separateLink[1] ?? "")/\(separateLink[2] ?? "")"
```

When the link comes only `https://product/` Im getting **Fatal error: Index out of range** even using the Optionals and String Interpolation, how can i guarantee that independently of the quantity of informations in my link the code wont break

Comment: What about checking that `separateLink.count > 2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the number of path components. However, ideally you should use the `URL` functions instead of manipulating the link as a `String`:

```
if var url = URL(string: "https://product/000000/product-name-type-color") {
    let pathComponents = url.pathComponents

    // "product" is not a path component, it's the host.
    // Path components are "/", "000000" and "product-name-type-color"
    if pathComponents.count > 2 {
        url = url.deletingLastPathComponent()
    }

    print(url)
}
```